# Flatten Spark Dataframe column of map/dictionary into multiple columns

Tags: python, pyspark

We have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
DataFrame[event: string, properties: map<string,string>]
```

Notice that there are two columns: `event` and `properties`. How do we split or flatten the `properties` column into multiple columns based on the key values in the `map`?

---

I notice I can do something like this:

```
newDf = df.withColumn("foo", col("properties")["foo"])
```

which produce a `Dataframe` of

```
DataFrame[event: string, properties: map<string,string>, foo: String]
```

But then I would have to do these for all the keys one by one. Is there a way to do them all automatically? For example, if there are `foo`, `bar`, `baz` as the keys in the `properties`, can we flatten the `map`:

```
DataFrame[event: string, foo: String, bar: String, baz: String]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `explode()` function - it flattens the map by creating two additional columns - `key` and `value` for each entry:

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- properties: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

>>> df.select('event', explode('properties')).printSchema()
root
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

You can use pivot if you have a column with unique value you can group by. For example:

```
df.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id()) \
    .select('id', 'event', explode('properties')) \
    .groupBy('id', 'event').pivot('key').agg(first('value'))
```

Comment: That is interesting. But I was hoping that it can expand into N columns based on the available keys. Do you know if there is a way to achieve that?

Comment: You can use `pivot` if you have a column with unique value you can group by. For example: `df.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id()).select('id', 'event', explode('properties')).groupBy('id', 'event').pivot('key').agg(first('value'))`