# How to read multiple nested json objects in one file extract by pyspark to dataframe in Azure databricks?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I have .log file in ADLS which contain multiple nested Json objects as follows

```
{"EventType":3735091736,"Timestamp":"2019-03-19","Data":{"Id":"event-c2","Level":2,"MessageTemplate":"Test1","Properties":{"CorrId":"d69b7489","ActionId":"d0e2c3fd"}},"Id":"event-c20b9c7eac0808d6321106d901000000"}
{"EventType":3735091737,"Timestamp":"2019-03-18","Data":{"Id":"event-d2","Level":2,"MessageTemplate":"Test1","Properties":{"CorrId":"f69b7489","ActionId":"d0f2c3fd"}},"Id":"event-d20b9c7eac0808d6321106d901000000"}
{"EventType":3735091738,"Timestamp":"2019-03-17","Data":{"Id":"event-e2","Level":1,"MessageTemplate":"Test1","Properties":{"CorrId":"g69b7489","ActionId":"d0d2c3fd"}},"Id":"event-e20b9c7eac0808d6321106d901000000"}
```

**Need to read the above multiple nested Json objects in pyspark and convert to dataframe as follows**

```
EventType    Timestamp       Data.[Id]  ..... [Data.Properties.CorrId]    [Data.Properties. ActionId]
3735091736   2019-03-19      event-c2   ..... d69b7489                    d0e2c3fd   
3735091737   2019-03-18      event-d2   ..... f69b7489                    d0f2c3fd
3735091738    2019-03-17     event-e2   ..... f69b7489                    d0d2c3fd
```

For above I am using ***ADLS,Pyspark in Azure DataBricks***.

Does anyone know a general way to deal with above problem? Thanks!

Comment: Read row wise, and create a row, and keep appending to df

Comment: Can you please provide me an example for the same? As i am new to pyspark

Comment: Send me your log file

Comment: You can copy the text {"EventType.. and save it as a .log file.

Comment: you can find the file @ https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sPyG2-XnhtGBfEwZE-loc1OKGk2Aa54G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can read it into an RDD first. It will be read as a list of strings
2. You need to convert the json string into a native python datatype using 
   `json.loads()`
3. Then you can convert the RDD into a dataframe, and it can infer the schema directly using `toDF()`
4. Using the answer from [Flatten Spark Dataframe column of map/dictionary into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993176/flatten-spark-dataframe-column-of-map-dictionary-into-multiple-columns), you can explode the `Data` column into multiple columns. Given your `Id` column is going to be unique. Note that, explode would return `key`, `value` columns for each entry in the map type.
5. You can repeat the 4th point to explode the `properties` column.

Solution:

```
import json

rdd = sc.textFile("demo_files/Test20191023.log")
df = rdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x)).toDF()
df.show()
# +--------------------+----------+--------------------+----------+
# |                Data| EventType|                  Id| Timestamp|
# +--------------------+----------+--------------------+----------+
# |[MessageTemplate ...|3735091736|event-c20b9c7eac0...|2019-03-19|
# |[MessageTemplate ...|3735091737|event-d20b9c7eac0...|2019-03-18|
# |[MessageTemplate ...|3735091738|event-e20b9c7eac0...|2019-03-17|
# +--------------------+----------+--------------------+----------+

data_exploded = df.select('Id', 'EventType', "Timestamp", F.explode('Data'))\
    .groupBy('Id', 'EventType', "Timestamp").pivot('key').agg(F.first('value'))
# There is a duplicate Id column and might cause ambiguity problems
data_exploded.show()

# +--------------------+----------+----------+--------+-----+---------------+--------------------+
# |                  Id| EventType| Timestamp|      Id|Level|MessageTemplate|          Properties|
# +--------------------+----------+----------+--------+-----+---------------+--------------------+
# |event-c20b9c7eac0...|3735091736|2019-03-19|event-c2|    2|          Test1|{CorrId=d69b7489,...|
# |event-d20b9c7eac0...|3735091737|2019-03-18|event-d2|    2|          Test1|{CorrId=f69b7489,...|
# |event-e20b9c7eac0...|3735091738|2019-03-17|event-e2|    1|          Test1|{CorrId=g69b7489,...|
# +--------------------+----------+----------+--------+-----+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: @MangeshT. You're welcome! Please upvote if it was helpful :)

Comment: Sure.
How to extract values from 'Properties''column as it is showing the 'String' Data Type.

root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EventType: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Exception: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Level: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LocalTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MessageTemplate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Properties: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RenderedMessage: string (nullable = true)

Comment: @MangeshT. not sure why it is reading it as `Properties='{CorrId=d69b7489, ActionId=d0e2c3fd}'`

Comment: Yeah Because the `Data`' is of map<string,string> type

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the data by following code.

````
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
DF = spark.read.json("demo_files/Test20191023.log") 

DF.select(col('Id'),col('EventType'),col('Timestamp'),col('Data.Id'),col('Data.Level'),col('Data.MessageTemplate'),
          col('Data.Properties.CorrId'),col('Data.Properties.ActionId'))\
  .show()```

***Result*** 

+--------------------+----------+----------+--------+-----+---------------+--------+--------+
|                  Id| EventType| Timestamp|      Id|Level|MessageTemplate|  CorrId|ActionId|
+--------------------+----------+----------+--------+-----+---------------+--------+--------+
|event-c20b9c7eac0...|3735091736|2019-03-19|event-c2|    2|          Test1|d69b7489|d0e2c3fd|
|event-d20b9c7eac0...|3735091737|2019-03-18|event-d2|    2|          Test1|f69b7489|d0f2c3fd|
|event-e20b9c7eac0...|3735091738|2019-03-17|event-e2|    1|          Test1|g69b7489|d0d2c3fd|
+--------------------+----------+----------+--------+-----+---------------+--------+--------+
````